# Is there a Way to Toggle GTK Switch to OFF state under a specific condition in Python, programmatically?

Tags: python, linux, gtk, pygtk

I Am trying to set a GTK Switch to OFF state ,from ON State, without the human intervention such as mouse click or keyboard key press.

So is there any way to toggle switch states via Python+GTK ?

Any guidance on this could be helping !!

Comment: Did you try `set_active()` ? https://python-gtk-3-tutorial.readthedocs.io/en/latest/button_widgets.html#switch

Comment: Did you read https://docs.gtk.org/gtk3/ - once you did found a C function from GTK3, finding its Python equivalent is easy!

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch, thanks for the suggestion, will read the doc !